Position text in div that uses flex
I'm trying to add text in the top right corner of the screen to use it as a menu over a div that is using flex (the section1 div would contain an image irl). However, it keeps staying in the top left corner.
Here's my code.


.section{
    height: 100vh; /* 100% of the viewport height */
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    position:relative;
    }

#section1{
margin:0;
height:100vh;
width:100%;}

#section2{
margin:0;
height:100vh;
width:100%;}

        
.menu{
    position: relative;
    z-index:3;
    text-align: right;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding:10px;
  }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="section" id="section1">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li>Sculptures</li>
        <li>Quotes</li>
        <li>Reviews</li>
    </ul>
</video>
</div>
<div id='section2' class="section">
<p>section 2</p>
</div>
<div id='section3' class='section'>
<p>section 3<p>
</div>
</body>

</html>



I tried using margin-left:auto; but it's not working. Even if I had it in the css it doesn't show when I inspect the element.

Is fixed positioning what you are after? Or absolute positioning? An element with a fixed position will not scroll, an element with an absolute position will scroll.


body {
  margin: 0
}

.section {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

#section1 {
  background: pink;
}

#section2 {
  background: lime;
}

#section3 {
  background: cyan;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
<nav>
  <a>Sculptures</a>
  <a>Quotes</a>
  <a>Reviews</a>
</nav>

<div id="section1" class="section">
  <p>section 1</p>
</div>

<div id='section2' class="section">
  <p>section 2</p>
</div>

<div id='section3' class='section'>
  <p>section 3<p>
</div>



